# Pandas find missing 15 minutes intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customerId' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B'],
    'startOf15Min' : ['2019-07-30T00:00:00', '2019-07-30T00:15:00',
       '2019-07-30T07:00:00', '2019-07-30T07:15:00',
       '2019-07-30T07:30:00', '2019-07-30T07:45:00',
       '2019-07-30T08:00:00', '2019-07-30T00:00:00',
       '2019-07-30T00:15:00', '2019-07-30T06:30:00',
       '2019-07-30T06:45:00', '2019-07-30T07:00:00',
       '2019-07-30T07:15:00', '2019-07-30T07:30:00',
       '2019-07-30T07:45:00', '2019-07-30T08:00:00']
}, columns=['customerId', 'startOf15Min'])
df.startOf15Min = pd.to_datetime(df.startOf15Min)

df
```

[image]

I need to find out missing 15 minutes interval between two datetimes.
For example if :

```
fr_timestamp = 2019-07-30 06:00:00
to_timestamp = 2019-07-30 09:00:00
```

For customer A, missing 15 minutes intervals are: **06:00, 06:15, 06:30, 06:45 and 08:15, 08:30, 08:45**.

For customer B, missing 15 minutes intervals are: **06:00, 06:15 and 08:15, 08:30, 08:45**.

How to find these intervals?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
intv = pd.date_range('2019-07-30 06:00:00','2019-07-30 09:00:00', freq='15Min', closed='left')
missing = df.groupby('customerId')['startOf15Min'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in intv if i not in x])

print(missing[0])
print(missing[1])
```

Output:

```
[Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:00:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:15:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:30:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:45:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:15:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:30:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:45:00', freq='15T')]

[Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:00:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 06:15:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:15:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:30:00', freq='15T'),
 Timestamp('2019-07-30 08:45:00', freq='15T')]
```

Comment: For missing[0] and missing[1] i get all timestamps from 
2019-07-30 06:00:00 to 
2019-07-30 08:45:00, 
12 of them. I can't figure out why.

Anywhay, as I have a lot of rows (hundreds of millions), I hoped to avoid usage of apply/for.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually I have sorted it out in the following way.
I have generated date_range as you did. Than I have created multiindex.from_product of unique customers and generated date_range.
Finally, I have merged (left) multiindex with my dataframe. 
All mising intervals are NaT's. 
In that case I have avoided usage of apply/for.

Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Best regards.