# Inserting rows into a csv-file using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, insert

I have data in a csv-file with raw input data that looks like this:

```
...
2015-01-02,11:00:00,1136.02
2015-01-02,11:05:00,1133.02
2015-01-02,11:10:00,1131.09
2015-01-02,11:25:00,1130.02
2015-01-02,11:30:00,1138.31
2015-01-02,11:40:00,1132.23
2015-01-02,11:45:00,1137.45
...
```

Now, I want to fill up the missing time intervals (e.g. 11:15:00, 11:20:00) with the price of the last time interval, so it looks like this:

```
...
2015-01-02,11:00:00,1136.02
2015-01-02,11:05:00,1133.02
2015-01-02,11:10:00,1131.09
2015-01-02,11:15:00,1131.09
2015-01-02,11:20:00,1131.09
2015-01-02,11:25:00,1130.02
2015-01-02,11:30:00,1138.31
2015-01-02,11:35:00,1138.31
2015-01-02,11:40:00,1132.23
2015-01-02,11:45:00,1137.45
...
```

This should be done from 09.30 - 16.00. Also the dataframe is saved as

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, names=['date', 'minute', 'price'])
```

These new and duplicated rows should finally be inserted into the actual csv-file. The date and time should still be saved as separate columns and as strings in the csv-document.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267868/pandas-find-missing-15-minutes-intervals ?

Comment: The same problem is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/73269147/19255749